# jquery toggle from several multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-select

I have a table and I would like to filter row that is not selected from a multiple select.

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tr>
      <td>Working Visa</td>
      <td>Blond</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Student Visa</td>
      <td>Brown</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like, when I select (or unselect) values from one of the select, it filter rows where not selected values are.

```
<select class="select" multiple>
   <option value="Working Visa"></option>
   <option value="Student Visa"></option>
</select>
<select class="select" multiple>
   <option value="Blond"></option>
   <option value="Brown"></option>
</select>
```

What I did so far

```
$("select.select").change( function() {

    $(this).each(function() {
        var valeurs = $(this).val();
        //console.log(valeurs);
        $("#MyTable tr").show();
        $("td").not("td."+valeurs).parent("tr").hide();
    });

});
```

When click on "Working Visa" I want that only rows with "Working Visa" will be shown. But if I click on Blond too, row with Working Visa AND Blond only will be show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine the number of `select` elements that have selected options:

```
var num= $('select.select').has('option:selected').length;
```

Hide all the rows:

```
  $('#myTable tr').hide();
```

Show only rows in which the `td`s that match selected options equals the number in step 1.

```
  $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
    if(num === $(this).find('td').filter(function() {
                  return $('option:selected:contains("'+$(this).text()+'")').length;
               }).length
      ) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
```

This will work even if you add additional `select` elements and table columns.

```js
$('select.select').change(function() {
  var num= $('select.select').has('option:selected').length;

  $('#myTable tr').hide();
  
  $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
    if(num === $(this).find('td').filter(function() {
                  return $('option:selected:contains("'+$(this).text()+'")').length;
               }).length
      ) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#myTable tr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" multiple>
   <option value="Working Visa">Working Visa</option>
   <option value="Student Visa">Student Visa</option>
</select>
<select class="select" multiple size="5">
   <option value="Blond">Blond</option>
   <option value="Black">Black</option>
   <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
   <option value="Auburn">Auburn</option>
</select>

<table id="myTable">
   <tr>
      <td>Working Visa</td>
      <td>Blond</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Working Visa</td>
      <td>Black</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Student Visa</td>
      <td>Brown</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Student Visa</td>
      <td>Auburn</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of the selected values, hide all the `tr` elements, and then filter the `tr` elements based on whether they contain the selected values and show the ones that do.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4n73nh5z/)

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var selectedValues = $('select option:selected').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  $('table tr').hide().filter(function() {
    var self = this,
      containsValue = true;

    selectedValues.forEach(function(value) {
      if (!$(self).find('td:contains(' + value + ')').length) {
        containsValue = false;
      }
    });

    return containsValue;
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Working Visa</td>
    <td>Blond</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Student Visa</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Working Visa</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Student Visa</td>
    <td>Blond</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<select class="select" multiple>
  <option value="Working Visa">Working Visa</option>
  <option value="Student Visa">Student Visa</option>
</select>
<select class="select" multiple>
  <option value="Blond">Blond</option>
  <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
</select>
```

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var selectedValues = $('select option:selected').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  $('table tr').hide().filter(function() {
    var self = this,
      containsValue = true;

    selectedValues.forEach(function(value) {
      if (!$(self).find('td:contains(' + value + ')').length) {
        containsValue = false;
      }
    });

    return containsValue;
  }).show();
});
```

If you want to handle instances where multiple values can be selected:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8or9Lkkc/)

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var selectedValues = $('select:has(option:selected)').map(function() {
    return [$(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get()];
  }).get();

  $('table tr').hide().filter(function() {
    var self = this,
        containsValue = true;

    selectedValues.forEach(function(valueArray) {
      var hasAtLeastOne = false;

      valueArray.forEach(function(value) {
        if ($(self).find('td:contains(' + value + ')').length) {
          hasAtLeastOne = true;
        }
      });

      containsValue = hasAtLeastOne;
    });

    return containsValue;
  }).show();
});
```

Comment: Looks really nice but when you select multiple value in the same select, it just hide all. I am thinking to use an ajax request, this seem to makes things more difficult

Comment: @orugari Select box are used so that user should be able to select only one value from it 

this solution is working correctly

Comment: @NEO-xx You can actually ctrl+click in order to select multiples or unselect selected options.

Comment: @NEO-xx The question is about multiple selected items though. That's not the answer.. haha.. I'll have an updated solution posted in a few minutes..

Comment: @NEO-xx I need to select multiple values, I don't know how remove the multiple attribute will help me

Comment: @JoshCrozier Actually I am trying to use an ajax way to do it, but I am getting `tmp is null` error when I select a value from two select and I have no idea what is it. I cannot post an other question yet though.